# Patents age is listed as over 2011 years on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

The new Patents site (launched yesterday) is listed as 2011 years, 8 months old on the main [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) page.

[image: Patents Age]

Comment: Interesting, is this an easter-egg type thing?

Comment: So patent has had history of over 2000 years old, wait... What?

Comment: @Adel If it were an easter egg, I'd expect the [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/) site to be right around the same age.  ;)

Comment: Just SE preparing to sue Apple I guess. "Patents? We had patents way before you did. We have patents on patents"

Comment: @BilltheLizard and [Judaism](http://mi.yodeya.com) to be even older ^_^

Comment: There can be no prior art for us...   Er, nice catch - we're on it.

Comment: It's only dated that way so no one can claim a patent on sites on patents

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually an API bug, we're not returning a launch date for patents since it never went through Area 51.

This will be fixed in the next API deploy (should be a handful of minutes from now), and when the site stats fall out of cache on stackexchange.com everything should make sense again.