# Wrong site age for Ask Patents in SE site list

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats, ask-patents

I was just looking through the list of  [All sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) to see new sites. I was surprised to see Ask Parents stats: 2.8k questions, 4.4k answers, nearly 10k users and site age is only 3 months!!

> [image]

So, with extreme curiosity, I've tried to trace it on Area51 but haven't succeed. Then I suspected about it's age. I visited it and tried to find earliest post but /q/1,2 etc. redirected me to tour page finally from meta /q/1 and  from main /q/16, I got that Ask Patents might be came in picture on 5 Sept, 2012.

Meanwhile I found the reason why there is no Area51 entry from [What is "Ask Patents" and why is it secret?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146103/260388) (I've also remembered by related [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284184/260388)).

Anyway, the site age `3m` (3 months) looks clearly a **bug**.

Comment: You could have just gone to the last page of [the questions list, sorted by newest](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions?page=187&sort=newest) :)

Comment: @Cai Yes, /q/16 is actually found in that way.

Comment: I just checked the [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=default&run=true) endpoint and there the field: `open_beta_date` says `1482255693` which converts to *Tue Dec 20 2016 18:41:33 GMT+0100* so that matches what you see. Launch date is Thu Sep 20 2012 03:57:06 GMT+0200. Not sure why or if the open_beta_date got edited/adjusted, it is weird indeed. Good find!

Comment: [Not the first bug with its age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147877/152859), it all happens because it never went through Area 51, so they have some hack in place to mimick its age somehow. Probably when developers change stuff, they forget those hacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wrong date was recorded against the site creation date.

I've updated to the correct date and following cache expiration all should be correct here.